# For loop and Linear regression

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, linear-regression

Good evening,

I would like to reiterate both a subsetting and a linear regression, over the same data frame.

```
#I get the unique codes of the articles
codes = np.unique(data["cod_id"])

#Split
X = data['price']
y = data["quantity"]

accuracy = []
for i in np.nditer(codes):
    data = data.loc[df["cod_id"] == i]

#Arrange an if statement to avoid 0-element arrays, while splitting (80% train, 20% test)

    if int(len(data)) <= 2:

        X_train = X 
        y_train = y  

        # Test dataset 
        X_test = X 
        y_test = y 
    else:
        t = 0.8
        t = int(t*len(data)) 

        #Split     
        t = int(t*len(data)) 
        # Train dataset 
        X_train = X[:t] 
        y_train = y[:t]  

        # Test dataset 
        X_test = X[t:] 
        y_test = y[t:]

    #Run the Algorithm
    lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

    predicted_test_tr = lr.predict(X_test)

    pred_cost = (X_test["price"] * predicted_test_tr).sum()
    real_cost = (X_test["price"] * y_test).sum()

    delta = (pred_cost - owner_cost)/owner_cost 
    accuracy.append(delta)
```

But it reports a list "accuracy", as long as the "codes" one, but with the same value at each position

```
print(accuracy)

5.43234
5.43234
5.43234
...
```

How can I fix this issue?
Thank you

Comment: You are using the entire `DataFrame` every time, because at the top you have `X = data['price']` and then inside the loop you define training and test based on `X`. Define `X_test` and `Y_test` based on the slice you want, `X_train = data['price']` inside the loop

Comment: Okay thanks, but it keeps reporting "Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required."; do you have any suggestions? @ALollz

Comment: how is `df` in `data = data.loc[df["cod_id"] == i]` defined and how is `data` initialized? Is `data` the full dataset? Because this line will overwrite `data` the first time through the loop. I think you should be doing something like `data = df[df["cod_id"]==i]` where `df` is the full dataframe, but hard to say for sure without knowing how these dataframes are defined.